# How can I use self-signed HTTPS for my Ubuntu 20.04 autoinstall files?

Tags: server, certificates, autoinstall

I am trying to load an autoinstall config into an Ubuntu installation. I have my autoinstall configs hosted on two servers, one running https with company certs and one running http.

When the autoinstall URL is an http address Ubuntu will be automatically installed without issue. When the URL is https then the installation will not be automatic.

How can I check to make sure this is actually a certificate issue?

How can I load certs into Ubuntu during install time?

Comment: I am not sure about this specific use case but in general, the need to use self-signed certs is lesser now that things like certbot exist which will generate certs using the free EFF and mozilla-backed letsencrypt.org - having a cert with a trusted chain also removes the need to install a custom CA certificate on clients.  But a downside for something you're doing locally, I guess, is that the host needs to be findable on the global DNS system.

Answer (score 0):

Update

You cannot use self signed certificates when using autoinstall files. You may not use HTTPS at all. Only HTTP is supported because the kernel has not yet installed the TLS and certificate management stack.

One option is packaging your autoinstall file into an ubuntu ISO and editing the grub config file to add custom autoinstall args. You can host this ISO somewhere secure and netboot that.